# How come Java TinyB does not see the same devices hcitool does?

Tags: java, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to write a Java app that scans for a specific BLE device. I decided to use TinyB library and start with testing some examples.

Unfortunately, these do not see my device (it does not show up in `BluetoothManager.getDevices()`) even though `hcitool lescan` shows it. Examples can detect my phone, so it looks like library works, but not for BLE devices.

How do I make it find the same devices hcitool does? Maybe I should use some other library?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'll be polling `hcitool lescan` and messaging my app whether device was found.